# Non-negative linear combination equal to sum of one component

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $V$ be a (finite) $n$-dimensional real vector space. Suppose that $v^1, ..., v^n \in V$ satisfy:

1. For all $i \leq n$, $v^i_i \geq 0$ and $v^i_{j \neq i} \leq 0$.
2. For all $i \leq n$, $\sum_{j \leq n} v^j_i \geq 0$.

Claim: For all $i \leq n$, some *non-negative* [edited] linear combination of $v^1, ..., v^n$ has $i^{th}$ component $\sum_{j \leq n} v^j_i$ and all other components zero.

Seems basic but I'm not quite seeing the proof and can't find a reference. Can anyone help? Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried by induction?

Comment: Yes, let me sketch where I'm stuck: Suppose some non-neg linear combinations of $v_1$, ..., $v_k$ have the desired properties on their first $k$ components. By adding these to $v_{k+1}$ with the right non-negative weights we can cancel the first $k$ components of $v_{k+1}$. But how to ensure that this sum has positive $k+1$ component? Do you see how to get through that? Thanks very much.